# Can't get on_complete call-back in in_place_editor to work

Tags: scriptaculous

I'm using the in_place_editor capability in a Rails application. When returning from the Ajax call to the server where the database objects have been updated, I would like to use the :on_complete callback to make some additional updates in the view. Unfortunateöly I can't get the :on_complete to work.

To test, this is what I have in the view:

```
<%= in_place_editor_field "localization", 'sv', {}, {:cols => 11, :on_complete => 'function() {alert(1);}'} %>
```

Doesn't work and the Javascript console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function() {alert(1);} has no method 'bind'
```

Doing this:

```
<%= in_place_editor_field "localization", 'sv', {}, {:cols => 11, :on_complete => 'alert(1);'} %>
```

Results in:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object alert(1); has no method 'bind'
```

Can anybody say what's going on here? Does anybody have an example using on_complete?

Answer (score 0):

If others run into the same problem, I made an ugly workaround which I'm using until somebody comes up with a better answer. I patched the scriptaculous controls.js to check if there is a defined on-completion callback and if there is to call it, as follows:

```
wrapUp: function(transport) {
this.leaveEditMode();
// Can't use triggerCallback due to backward compatibility: requires
// binding + direct element
// Beginning of ugly patch:
    if(typeof editOnComplete == 'function') { 
        editOnComplete(this.element); 
    }
// End of ugly patch
this._boundComplete(transport, this.element);
```

}
});